# Discord.JS GET Request to API: Error 401: Unauthorised

Tags: discord, get, fetch

I am making a discord bot that redirects you to my webserver when you click 'Authorise this Bot'. Once it has done that, my webserver will use the provided 'identify' scope to give the user a certain role in my server. When I am trying to send a GET request to the discord API, using fetch(), it just keeps failing. I am sure this is a simple fix but here I am because I am stitched for answers. Here is my code that makes the request:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){


const query = url.parse(req.url).query;
  const [accessToken, tokenType] = [query.split('=')[1], query.split('=')[0]];

  if (!accessToken) {
    // Show 'verification failed' page
    console.log('No access token found.');
    res.render('index');
  }

  const getUserDetails = async (accessToken) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    })
  
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json);
  }

  getUserDetails(accessToken);

  res.render('index');
});
```

Any help is appreciated very much.